Save buffer version to register and restore buffer to specific version
I use the undo functionality via u all the time and redo less frequently.
I just now noticed, however, that the status bar reports change numbers, or perhaps buffer version numbers.
[No Name] [+]                                                                                                                                                              5,1            All
1 change; after #4  21 seconds ago

I'm wondering how to manipulate these buffer version numbers.
More specifically, I'm wondering

Is there a way to save buffer versions to registers?
Is there a way to restore the buffer contents to a particular version, either by number or by register?


Based off reading the source at the time of writing, I suspect that moving around by sequence number is possible, since the undo_time function shown below can use "absolute sequence numbers".
Although it's possible that those sequence numbers refer to branches of history rather than specific states.
/*
 * Undo or redo over the timeline.
 * When "step" is negative go back in time, otherwise goes forward in time.
 * When "sec" is FALSE make "step" steps, when "sec" is TRUE use "step" as
 * seconds.
 * When "file" is TRUE use "step" as a number of file writes.
 * When "absolute" is TRUE use "step" as the sequence number to jump to.
 * "sec" must be FALSE then.
 */
    void
undo_time(
    long    step,
    int     sec,
    int     file,
    int     absolute)
{

https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/7d755d8ef328a3eced18c57ea1b569898cc448a2/src/undo.c
However, I'm skeptical that the undo state can be stored in a register, since, according to the documentation, some register states are restored upon executing an undo or redo.

I believe the index you get is the index in the undo list and not a version number. It changes at every edition.

You have to do it manually: Go to a undo sequence state, copy the whole buffer to a register. Go to a different version, compare.

Take a look at :help undo-tree, which mentions g- and g+. There's other commands there, which you can use to "restore the buffer contents to a particular version[] by number."
There's also :help undotree(), which you can use to build sophisticated programs. For example, I use a plugin mbbill/undotree which gives a nice UI on top of the undotree, and includes diffs. Given that, I suspect you could dig into the code and look for a way to get the buffer contents of a particular version to store in a register or dump to a new buffer.
